# Arrow overlaps connection

Tags: jsplumb

I use JsPlumb to connect various div. The options i use for connection is as follows,

```
var option = {
     anchors: ["RightMiddle", "Bottom"],
     connectorStyle: { strokeWidth: 0.5, stroke: "#243CA8"},
     connector: ["Flowchart", { stub: [35, 70], midpoint: 0, cornerRadius: 1 }],
     paintStyle: { stroke: "#243CA8", strokeWidth: 30},
     overlays: [["Arrow", { location: 1, width: 65, length: 32 }]]
};
```

But the arrow overlaps on connector and output is not looking good.

[image]

I also tried setting overlay options 'location:-1' but still does not make any difference and also tried setting 'gap:10' for connector but it applies for both arrow overlay and connector by which the problem is still same but with space between element and connector. I cannot find anyother solution. Can anyone please suggest a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was trying different options and accidentally came across the solution which is mentioned nowhere.

I **just changed the 'location: 1' option of overlays to 'location: [0,1]'** and it worked. Had no idea it was possible and it is mentioned nowhere. This is to help those who are struggling with the same issue!